# Recursively adding .org files in a top-level directory for org-agenda-files takes a long time

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'm trying to find a way to quickly recurse through every subdirectory searching for org files. I've found several solutions ([Elisp Cookbook](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook#toc57), and several [solutions](https://gist.github.com/dmgerman/5675462) on [github](https://github.com/suvayu/.emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/nifty.el#L50)), but they don't handle my real world usage (hundreds of directories (and subdirectories) and hundreds of org files). They seem to run forever on my system (Windows 7, with max-lisp-eval-depth = 10000).   My work around is to add each directory manually to my org-agenda-list, but it's annoying and I know I've probably forgotten some.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about storing the list of org-agenda directories in a file that you (automatically) update every once in a while, when you know the direcory structure has changed and you have some time.

You could for example use something like this:

```
;; From http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ElispCookbook#toc58
(defun directory-dirs (dir)
  "Find all directories in DIR."
  (unless (file-directory-p dir)
    (error "Not a directory `%s'" dir))
  (let ((dir (directory-file-name dir))
        (dirs '())
        (files (directory-files dir nil nil t)))
    (dolist (file files)
      (unless (member file '("." ".."))
        (let ((file (concat dir "/" file)))
          (when (file-directory-p file)
            (setq dirs (append (cons file
                                     (directory-dirs file))
                               dirs))))))
    dirs))


(setq my-org-agenda-root "~/org")
(setq my-org-agenda-files-list "~/.emacs.d/org-agenda-list.el")

(defun my-update-org-agenda-files ()
  "Create or update the `my-org-agenda-files-list' file.

This file contains elisp code to set `org-agenda-files' to a
recursive list of all children under `my-org-agenda-root'. "
  (interactive)
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert
     ";; Warning: this file has been automatically generated\n"
     ";; by `my-update-org-agenda-files'\n")
    (let ((dir-list (directory-dirs my-org-agenda-root))
          (print-level nil)
          (print-length nil))
      (cl-prettyprint `(setq org-agenda-files (quote ,dir-list))))
    (write-file my-org-agenda-files-list)))

(load my-org-agenda-files-list)
```

Every once in a while, run <kbd>M-x</kbd>`my-update-org-agenda-files` to update the list.

Answer (score 6):

Haven't seen other people post this, so I will do.
Have you tried load "find-list" library and use its "find-lisp-find-files" function?
I added these lines in my org config and it works, but it may not fit your performance requirement:

`(load-library "find-lisp")
(setq org-agenda-files
   (find-lisp-find-files "FOLDERNAME" "\.org$"))`

source: http://emacs-orgmode.gnu.narkive.com/n5bQRs5t/o-multiple-recursive-directories-with-org-agenda-files

Answer (score 4):

The following code works well in emacs 24.3+:

```
;; Collect all .org from my Org directory and subdirs
(setq org-agenda-file-regexp "\\`[^.].*\\.org\\'") ; default value
(defun load-org-agenda-files-recursively (dir) "Find all directories in DIR."
    (unless (file-directory-p dir) (error "Not a directory `%s'" dir))
    (unless (equal (directory-files dir nil org-agenda-file-regexp t) nil)
      (add-to-list 'org-agenda-files dir)
    )
    (dolist (file (directory-files dir nil nil t))
        (unless (member file '("." ".."))
            (let ((file (concat dir file "/")))
                (when (file-directory-p file)
                    (load-org-agenda-files-recursively file)
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
(load-org-agenda-files-recursively "/path/to/your/org/dir/" ) ; trailing slash required
```

It does not require intermediate files creation and you can put it on a shortcut as well.

To be able to refile to any file found add this:

```
(setq org-refile-targets
      '((nil :maxlevel . 3)
        (org-agenda-files :maxlevel . 1)))
```

Comment: It is also possible to configure emacs to get the agenda files list for refiling. See edit above.

Comment: Just added a fix to add to the list only directories, which already contain .org files.

Answer (score 1):

As of Emacs 25, you can use `directory-files-recursively` which returns all files matching a regex from a root directory.

```
(defun org-get-agenda-files-recursively (dir)
  "Get org agenda files from root DIR."
  (directory-files-recursively dir "\.org$"))

(defun org-set-agenda-files-recursively (dir)
  "Set org-agenda files from root DIR."
  (setq org-agenda-files 
    (org-get-agenda-files-recursively dir)))

(defun org-add-agenda-files-recursively (dir)
  "Add org-agenda files from root DIR."
  (nconc org-agenda-files 
    (org-get-agenda-files-recursively dir)))

(setq org-agenda-files nil) ; zero out for testing

(org-set-agenda-files-recursively "~/Github") ; test set

(org-add-agenda-files-recursively "~/Dropbox") ; test add
```

You can view the contents of `org-agenda-files` by typing `C-hv org-agenda-files`.

Answer (score 1):

Little late to the party, and probably not the answer you were hoping for, but the only way I found to speed up my agenda load times was by not including some directories which had thousands of org files.

```
(setq org-directory "~/org/"
      my-agenda-dirs '("personal" "projects" "todos" "work")
      org-agenda-files (mapcan (lambda (x) (directory-files-recursively
                                             (expand-file-name x org-directory)
                                             "\.org$"))
                               my-agenda-dirs))
```

Essentially rather than recursing over my entire org dir I only recurse through a select few of it's subdirs.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried "recursive directory listing" at Emacs startup. It simply is way to loooong to be usable. So, try to stick with a limited number of "root" directories where you put your agenda files.

Even better is sticking with "~/org", and possibly a few subdirs like "work" and "personal", and that's it. You can put there your agenda files, and have links Inside them to your real project root dirs.

I know, this is not optimal, but I don't have anything better right now.